# Getting error Could not compile dependency :mimerl

Tags: compilation, dependencies, elixir, phoenix-framework

```
(Mix) Could not compile dependency :mimerl, "/home/ubuntu/.mix/rebar3
bare compile --paths "/var/www/qserv/elixirbackend/_build/dev/lib/*/ebin"" 
command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile mimerl", 
update it with "mix deps.update mimerl" or clean it with "mix deps.clean mimerl"
```

I am getting this error on my server. Everything was working perfectly fine but after restarting my server, started facing the above mentioned issue.

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [ds:1:1:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.6.3 (compiled with OTP 19)
```

Comment: I also posted question on elixirforum https://elixirforum.com/t/getting-error-could-not-compile-dependency-mimerl/13460

Comment: If this was working fine, what did you change?  Restarting the server should not have caused this issue to occur.

Comment: I just run the server in `iex mode` for debugging and after that I run mix deploy, which in turn will `mix deps.get` and will run the server

Comment: Add your `mix.exs` to your question.  No one can suggest anything without additional details.

Comment: You might also try `mix compile.erlang` with a `--force` flag or a `--return-errors` flag as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the instructions mentioned by `Elixir forum user`

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-178:/var/www/qserv/elixir-backend$ sudo rm -rf /home/ubuntu/.mix/rebar3
ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-178:/var/www/qserv/elixir-backend$ mix local.rebar --force
```

and Then I also changed git permissions which I noticed while running mix phx.server

warning: unable to access ‘/home/ubuntu/.config/git/ignore’: Permission denied
warning: unable to access ‘/home/ubuntu/.config/git/attributes’: Permission denied

So, basically the problem was somehow I messed up permissions(I dont remember/know exactly how).

Credit goes to `Norbert Melzer` elixir forum user([Complete post](https://elixirforum.com/t/getting-error-could-not-compile-dependency-mimerl/13460/24)).